# Is it possible remove a session variable with a timer?

Tags: vb.net, session, session-variables

I want to remove a session variable using a timer. I have this class.

```
Public Class SessionKiller
    Private WithEvents mclsTimer As Timer
    Private mstrSessionKey As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal lstrSessionKey As String)
        mstrSessionKey = lstrSessionKey

        mclsTimer = New Timer(3000)
        mclsTimer.AutoReset = False
        mclsTimer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnTimedEvent(ByVal lobjSource As Object, lclsEvent As ElapsedEventArgs) Handles mclsTimer.Elapsed
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(mstrSessionKey)
    End Sub
End Class
```

But the `current` variable is nothing. Is it possible remove a session variable this way?

Comment: Please add the code where you acquire/create the session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using a pointer to `session` var.

```
Public Class SessionKiller
    Private WithEvents mclsTimer As Timer
    Private mstrSessionKey As String
    Private mclsSession As HttpSessionStateBase

    Public Sub New(ByVal lstrSessionKey As String, _
                   ByVal lclsSession As HttpSessionStateBase)
        mstrSessionKey = lstrSessionKey
        mclsSession = lclsSession

        mclsTimer = New Timer(3000)
        mclsTimer.AutoReset = False
        mclsTimer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnTimedEvent(ByVal lobjSource As Object, lclsEvent As ElapsedEventArgs) Handles mclsTimer.Elapsed
        mclsSession.Remove(mstrSessionKey)
    End Sub
End Class
```